# Creating unique combination of unique pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I'm trying to create a tournament system that will pair players together. Each tournament will have multiple of 4 players. Each player will only ever be paired with another player once. Those pairs will only ever play against another pair once. I believe the algorithm is `(n-1)*(n/4)` where n is the number of players.

Here’s the code:

```
function generateCombinations(arr) {
  let result = [];

  function combination(start, current) {
    if (current.length === 2) {
      result.push(current);
      return;
    }

    for (let i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let newCurrent = current.concat(arr[i]);
      if (new Set(newCurrent).size !== newCurrent.length) {
        continue;
      }
      combination(i + 1, newCurrent);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    combination(i + 1, [arr[i]]);
  }

  let finalResult = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i += 2) {
    let found = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < finalResult.length; j++) {
      if (finalResult[j][0][0] === result[i][0] && finalResult[j][0][1] === result[i][1]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      finalResult.push([result[i], result[i + 1]]);
    }
  }

  return JSON.stringify(finalResult);
}

let elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let combinations = generateCombinations(elements);
console.log(combinations);
```

It incorrectly outputs `[[["a","b"],["a","c"]],[["a","d"],["b","c"]],[["b","d"],["c","d"]]]`It should instead output `[[["a","b"],["c","d"]],[["a","c"],["b","d"]],[["a","d"],["b","c"]]]`

The difference is that it each each unique pair of pairs should be unique overall. eg. `a+b` will be paired with `c+d` . It’s correctly creating the unique possible pairs, but is incorrectly pairing them with each other.

This code should handle multiples of 4 players up to 16 players.

`4 people = 3 rows of 2v2 8 people = 14 rows of 2v2 12 people = 33 rows of 2v2 16 people = 60 rows of 2v2`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple brute-force solution:

```js
function makeRounds(n) {
    let sets = []
    let rounds = []

    for (let r = 0; r < n - 1; r++) {
        sets.push({})
        rounds.push([])
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            for (let r = 0; r < n - 1; r++) {
                if (!sets[r][i] && !sets[r][j]) {
                    sets[r][i] = sets[r][j] = 1
                    rounds[r].push([i, j])
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return rounds
}

for (r of makeRounds(8))
   console.log(r.join(' '))
```

Basically, for each "round" maintain a set of "teams" (numbers) already in this round. Generate each possible pair `[a,b]` and put it in the first round whose respective set doesn't contain `a` or `b`.

Comment: Hmpf, looks like OP bailed on us. No award ceremony. For shame lol. Anyway, that was a fun issue to think about. I like your solution. Interesting that it does not produce deadlocks, where the last possible pairing was already inserted into another row. Very interesting. +1

Comment: @MoritzRingler: interestingly, I tried to invent a clever algorithm for that and quickly wrote this code to generate some outputs to play with... and realized that it is already fast enough for most purposes (like 1024 rounds per second on my PC).

Comment: Oh yes, it is actually quite efficient due to the lookup and because it doesn't backtrack but rather "track forward". I think it is n^3 (and n^4 without the lookup), right? Compared to my combinatory solution, which just iterates the results and still takes n^2, that is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Our friends, the math people, have an [algorithm for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3094469). It works by removing the last element from the list, and then going through the remaining elements, pairing the one at the index with the removed element, while also pairing elements with the same distance from the current index. For example, at index 2 with six elements, it will build the pairs `(2,5), (1,3), (0,4)`:

[image: pairs with n = 6 and i = 2]

Here is an implementation (`buildPairIndexes()`), which returns tuples of array indexes. Then `pairPlayers()` just gets the indexes and resolves them for the players.

```js
const players = new Array(6).fill(null).map((_, ix) => String.fromCharCode(97 + ix))

function buildPairIndexes(n) {
    if (n % 2 !== 0) {
        throw new Error(`${n} is an odd number`)
    }
    const pairings = []
    const max = n - 1
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        const pairing = [[max, i]]
        for (let k = 1; k < (n / 2); k++) {
            pairing.push([(i + k) % max, (max + i - k) % max])
        }
        pairings.push(pairing)
    }
    return pairings
}

function pairPlayers(players) {
    const pairings = buildPairIndexes(players.length)
    const pairIxToPlayer = (i) => players[(i + 1) % players.length]
    return pairings.map(pairing => pairing.map(pair => pair.map(pairIxToPlayer)))
}
console.log(pairPlayers(players))
```

Here is the output of just the indexes for six items:

```js
[
  [ [ 5, 0 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ],
  [ [ 5, 1 ], [ 2, 0 ], [ 3, 4 ] ],
  [ [ 5, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 0 ] ],
  [ [ 5, 3 ], [ 4, 2 ], [ 0, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 5, 4 ], [ 0, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
]
```